# BACnet IP routing with BACnet Broadcast Management Devices (BBMD)

Tags: routes, bacnet

I have the following setup with 2 BBMDs and a SIEMENS IP Router (Model S615):

[image: Topology]

The SIEMENS router is only configured with these firewall rules (except for IP and Port configuration), which should be all I need according to SIEMENS:

[image: Router configuration]

Both of the BBMDS are (currently) configured as such:

[image: BBMD Configuration]

Except the other one uses UDP port 47809.
Both use the router as default gateway on each subnet.

Problem is that the broadcasts are only distributed one way…. I get “I AM” broadcasts in my BACnet browser from the BACnet device, but I do NOT get “WHO IS” broadcasts to my BACnet device from the browser.
In other words, the 192.168.1.31 >> 10.83.87.31 is working but 10.83.87.31 >> 192.168.1.31 is not…

BBMD Device used: http://www.hvacrcontrol.com/bacnet-router/

Answer (score 1):

Check your BDTs (Broadcast Distribution Table). A BDT entry needs to specify "one hop" or "two hop", per entry, via the "broadcast distribution mask". For two hop, which I assume is your intended scenario, this mask needs to be 255.255.255.255

I don't know this equipment, you may want to confirm this with the manufacturer.

Comment: BDT entry as 192.168.1.31:47808 implies network mask is 255.255.255.255
BDT entry as 192.168.1.31/24:47808 means network mask is 255.255.255.0 
I have tried both unfortunately with same result...

Comment: It certainly seems that something is not operating as designed/expected. Are you able to get a wireshark capture at the Browser workstation (probably the easiest) and view the traffic to see if it makes sense? Else you could install an Ethernet switch with a mirror port between the network and each BBMD and capture traffic logs going in and out of the BBMDs. Nothing is simple anymore.

Comment: As an aside; try to lessen your reliance upon (UDP) 'Broadcasts', as (looking ahead) BACnet/SC is no longer relying upon BBMDs, and 'Broadcasts' are not strictly (/naturally) supported by IPv6 (- emulated using 'Multicast').